# Receiving MSMQ error after moving from Windows Server 2008 to 2016

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, msmq, windows-server-2016

I'll preface this by saying that I am not a Windows stack expert so I apologize if I mix up terms here.

We are currently migrating our application and related resources from Windows Server 2008 to 2016. Inside the cluster we have an MSMQ service (along with a local instance) that has dozens of queues for our application to use.

Everything was moved over into this new server. When I tested an enqueuing function through C# (using the path ./private$/{queuename}) the following error is thrown.

> The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.

I was then giving full control over the queues, tried to enqueue some data, then received this error again. So it being a permissions issue was ruled out.

This works in the prior version of Windows Server and the configurations are exactly the same according to our server team.

Now the only way to connect to use the FormatName (FormatName:DIRECT=OS:{clusterName}.{domain}.net). This breaks a good portion of our application since it expects the local path (which checks if the queue exists before queuing a message).

Is there some sort of change in 2016 that is causing this new behavior and, if so, is there some sort of configuration that is being looked over? I would prefer to continue the use of local paths if possible. If not then we will have to overhaul our 10-year old application.

EDIT: I should also mention I'm on a different domain than the cluster (pub.{domain}.net).

Comment: Well, are you sure the queues exist? Use Computer Management, Services and Applications, Message Queueing. https://www.infoworld.com/article/3060115/how-to-work-with-msmq-in-c.html It looks like you're using private queue which is good because they are the most simple ones.

Comment: They do exist, I am able to queue data by using the remote name, but not using the local path './private$/{queuename}. We were able to reach the queues using that path and then it would communicate with the cluster MSMQ. Now with the server upgraded, that method no longer works.

Comment: this should be ".\private$\queuename", not "./private$/queuename". And in a cluster case, you should use the cluster network name, not "." https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2013/03/20/how-to-install-and-cluster-msmq-on-windows-server-2012/

Comment: Sorry, the paths do indeed use '\', that was a typo on my part here. We had processes that were able to translate "." before the move which would connect to the cluster. It was only until the move to 2016 that MSMQ complained about not using the cluster network name. We discussed a solution and we are just going to rework our system's framework to not use MSMQ functions that break using remote paths.